# Usage of Spring Cloud Zookeeper instead of Spring Cloud Config Server for Actuator refresh context

Tags: spring-cloud, apache-zookeeper, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-zookeeper

**Spring Boot applications context needs to be refreshed after changing properties (in GIT repository) without a need of application redeployment.**

Can I consider using zookeeper to fetch application properties stored externally (in a separate GIT repository, yaml file) and apply them to /actuator/refresh endpoint of the services deployed in Kubernetes?

I`ve already seen plenty examples of Spring Cloud Config Server usage, but at least now I want to give a try of Zookeeper as it`s configured and used on our production for many purposes.

Maybe somebody tried to do such things and has a proper approach?

Comment: Yes, it will work similarly.

Comment: thanks, @spencergibb for confirmation
could You, please, advice how pushing to GIT repo and zookeeper update can be handled? is some custom implementation needed?

Comment: I know of no such implementation, it would need to be custom

Comment: I think there is something for consul though